Transformation of negatively skewed data
I asked a question and thanks to your feedback I noticed how unspecific and not thought through enough it was.
So, I am trying to be more specific.
I am currently trying to calculate a moderation analysis with anger (scores from 5 to 25) as the IV, age of males as the moderator and IPV variety as the dependent variable. The DV depicts the number of different forms of IPV a partner experienced. They can range from 0 to 5. 2 means f.e. that this person experienced 2 forms of IPV regardless of which ones specifically.
Most of my participants have experienced alls 5 forms (value 5).
Now I have found out that with ggplot and smoothing "loess" at least the interaction plot is not linear (looks more like cubic functions).
So I would like to calculate a non-linear model.
model_gam <- mgcv::gam(ipv_variety ~ s(dar_scaled) + s(age_scaled, k = 12) + ti(dar_scaled, age_scaled), data = merged_all_complete, method = "REML")
#alternative
gam1 <- lm(ipv_variety ~ ns(dar_scaled, 5) * age_scaled, data=merged_all_complete)

As far as I understood ( I can be incorrect) the family chosen depends on the distribution of the DV. And currently it is the default Gaussian which does not fit my data.
So I would like to know whether there is a family that fits my data or whether there is a way to transform my DV so that Gaussian fits.
I am relatively new, so I apologise if I overlooked some crucial details.
If there are more questions, I am happy to answer.
Thanks again.


Why the desire to transform to normality? 2.  "Skewed and has a 0" isn't enough information to select a distribution. Even if it were, you're looking at the marginal distribution of the response but in a GAM your model is for the conditional distributions, which may well look different from the marginal (and generally, from each other). You should talk more about the variable itself (of which you have said almost nothing), that may at least help rule out some possibilities.


As revised, the question text now has moved some distance from the original title. Your outcome (DV in your terms) is counted with values from 0 to 5, mostly 5. Consider that the marginal distribution consists in principle of 6 spikes and even if a transform was a good idea -- it isn't -- no transform could do anything but map 6 spikes to 6 different spikes and the highest spike would have the same frequency. The most crucial detail, however, is that a GAM doesn't sound at all appropriate for your outcome variable, but I am not an expert.

Thank you. Could you recommend another model?

Not without seeing more of your data, and perhaps not even then. If an outcome is nearly constant,  any model could be awkward.

The biggest question here is why you think it is important or desirable to have a normal distribution. Usually when normality is regarded as an ideal condition, it concerns the distribution of an outcome conditional on the predictors, which cannot be discussed helpfully in abstraction, as all depends on the outcome, the predictors, and plausible functional forms for their relationship.
Even if all data were positive, taking logarithms or square roots would indeed usually not change skewness in the desired direction. Specifically, logarithm of zero is not defined in any case.
Squaring or cubing might change skewness in the desired direction. On the whole I would not recommend that unless squaring or cubing were consistent with some dimensional analysis of the variables concerned, as when lengths are mapped to areas or volumes.
An approximately symmetrical distribution is not necessarily approximately normal.
In general, just knowing that a variable is negatively skewed and includes zeros is utterly insufficient for advising on any appropriate model, whether generalized additive or something else. Among many other details, it is important to know whether a variable has an upper bound in principle.
